# How to update existing merged Excel cells with Apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I can't update existing excel cells these are merged and borderd. I created an Excel file with styling and use as template. At my code-> firstly read that Excel file and update cells that I wish. No merge cells were ok . But merged cells can't insert datas.

It may be produce damage Excel file or empty data cells. I don't want to overwrite merged and bordered of existing cells. Here my code for reading and updating..

```
HashMap<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> streams = new HashMap<String, ByteArrayOutputStream>();
try {
    String appDir = System.getProperty("appDir");
    String resouceDir = appDir + System.getProperty("resourceDir");
    String templateDir = resouceDir + "/template";
    if (streams.keySet().size() <= 0) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = null;
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(templateDir +"/shipping_template.xlsx")); 
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow shippingRow = sheet.getRow(4);
        Cell cell = shippingRow.createCell((short) 36);
        cell.setCellValue("DOOM Bringer");
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(baos);
        streams.put(param, baos);
        baos.close();
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Apache POI is no longer supported.  They did one version of the Office 2007 changes to the way office documents are done and no longer support this.  I had done the same exact thing and you may want to consider using docx4j.  But regardless what you actually need to do is probably open with a file stream a new document and save it onto a temp location and make changes to the new document as you may corrupt the original if you do try to make changes to it.

Comment: thanks for your advice but I don't want to save it in any directory as my project demands. That was created and save in memory to download it by anchor tag. I realized that it can't be updated as like that. That has too many boiler plate codes to create a merged or span cells.

Comment: Actually when I say save a temp copy I meant open a temp and save it to the ram then update that temp then if the user so chooses save it.  Once you close the stream the temp copy is gone.  Its the same thing that Microsoft does with documents you are opening.  When you open a word document Office opens a stream with a temp document, it will be in the same location as the actual document and will have a ~$ as the first characters of the name.  Get what I am saying?

Comment: Yes , you are right . Thanks in advance. I will check my codes.

Comment: No problem.  I hope you get everything figured out.

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me

```
CellRangeAddress region = sheet.getMergedRegion(index);   
int rowNum = region.getFirstRow(); // or region.getLastRow()
int colIndex = region.getFirstColumn(); // or region.getLastColumn()
Cell dateCell = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colIndex);
dateCell.setCellValue(today.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```